# How to find formal way to say informal sentence in TV shows?

Tags: formality

A lot of online articles recommend learning spoken English from soap operas, such as Friends, and How I Met Your Mother. I know that most of the expressions in the TV shows are informal. They are good for daily informal conversations. However, I want to learn formal English as well, which can be formal spoken English and formal writing. More importantly, it is a good exercise to transfer between formal and informal sentences. It produces the following two questions.

1. How can I find the corresponding formal sentence for any sentence in the soap operas?

How can I find the corresponding informal sentence for any sentence in the formal TV shows, such as Ted talk or lectures?

Comment: Study English for 5-10 years.

Comment: It seems to me that you've already identified that soap operas use informal English and TED Talks use formal English. If you're really asking how you translate phrases between the two, there is no simple method. (Although informal English uses contractions and slang, for instance, while formal English does not.) All you can really do is follow both until you can pick up on the different patterns.

Comment: Please note, they are SOAP-operas, not soup-operas!

Comment: Also note that Friends and How I Met Your Mother are not soap operas.

Comment: Just for your use in the future, the term for those two shows is "sitcom" or "sit-com", which is an abbreviation for "situation comedy". Soap operas are generally (not always) daytime shows that have a lot of drama and that tell one long story, whereas a sitcom is generally a series of disconnected episodes featuring the same characters. Sitcoms tend to include more comedy and less drama.

Comment: In many cases it will be difficult to find 'the corresponding formal sentence for any sentence in the soap operas' because many of the things that are said in a casual chat among friends would not be said at all in a formal setting.

Answer (score 1):

*How can you find a formal version of something said informally in a Tv sitcom?*

It’s not only slang; it’s that there may be no one-to-one conversation whose topic is appropriate in a different setting. One formal term for this is *register.* How friends chat is different from conversations between a boss and an employee, a student and a teacher, a child and his grandparents, legislators discussing policy on the Senate floor.

I find that contractions are in fact used in formal speech, even sometimes (although very carefully) in academic journals, non-fiction books, and newspaper articles.

The TED talks you mention—as well as speeches and lectures—have frequent contractions. What they also have that conversations don’t have is complete, well-formed sentences. These talks are carefully written and organized, and often read from cue cards or a teleprompter.

On the other hand, interviews have some of the features of spontaneous conversations. An experienced person like Bill Gates may speak primarily in complete sentences, but every now and then a sentence is revised midway through, or a thought restarted, and a phrase too informal for a TED talk is used. There’s a recent Gates interview on the coronavirus pandemic that has some of these qualities.

The TV channels CSPAN-2 and CSPAN-3 have book discussions and lectures—some interviews and Q&A. You could compare these to sitcoms.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from word choices in slang and other idioms the most common difference I find between the two realms you mention is the use of contractions. The more formal the language the fewer contractions are used. These of course shorten word combinations and allow the speaker to talk faster.

For a real match between the two you might take some formal textbook of yours and ask an English speaking friend to re-read some text and make it more friendly. This might bring up useful questions and answers.

I cannot help but mention the following. The old time radio show *Damon Runyon Theater* was a series of stories about "low" uncultured characters running through the streets of the big city. The author had once been told to shun such characters because, among other things, their speech was terrible and filled with contractions. In writing these he saw to it that as "low" as these characters might be they Never used contractions. The contrast of their actions and their careful diction is often amusing to those not used to such restrictions.